# Как в python строку из символов с процентами раскодировать в русские буквы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

Работаю с модулем `socket`, получаю данные из формы POST запросом. Некоторые данные в форме- русский текст и приходят они в виде такой строки `%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%83`.

Есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека/модуль/пакет/метод, чтобы преобразовать эту строку в нормальную?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/946170/4928642

Comment: @Qwertiy, попробовал передать такую строку в метод `urllib.unquote()`, но выдало ошибку `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'unquote'`

Comment: @ЕгорСпириади, `from urllib.parse import unquote`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51800409/4928642

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно использовать либо unquote, либо unquote_plus ("+" преобразует в пробелы)

```
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus

src = "%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%83"
res = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(src, encoding="utf-8")
print(res)
```

> стэковерфлоу